# Change logging level of SQL queries logged by Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework core by default logs all executed SQL queries to the ASP.NET Core logger (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`). The default log level is Informational, but it seems a bit chatty to me for informational logging. I would prefer it at Debug or even Trace level.

Is there any way to configure EFCore to log these SQL queries at Debug (or Trace) level, instead of Informational level?

Comment: Hi @nick, did you find solution for this?

Comment: Haven't yet. Sorry.

Comment: While I still don't know how to accomplish this, it should be mentioned that the default logging level for SQL has been changed from Informational to Debug in EFCore 3.0-preview 3. See: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14523 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-execution-is-logged-at-debug-level

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Entity Framework Core 3.0 it's possible to change to logging level of SQL queries.
During to 3.0 previews all query execution logging was changed to `Debug` by default. Later this change got reverted and now it's configurable.

To do this override `OnConfiguring` in your `DbContext` and run the following snippet:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Debug)));
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-execution-is-logged-at-debug-level-reverted

Answer (score 2):

You can set log level of Microsoft or System messages individually.

For your EntityFramework chatty logging you can set this in your startup class.

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
    builder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Error);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the question. You're setting a filter. I don't want to filter the messages, I want to change the log level of a message.